# How to install Caffe2 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, caffe2

Facebook has released [caffe2](http://caffe2.ai/) recently - deep learning library.

How to install on Windows 7 system?

Answer (score 3):

As of now windows build for caffe2 is in beta mode and only supports windows 10. Try using docker.

Answer (score 3):

The webpage says that

> Windows 10 or greater is required to run Caffe2.
>   Windows build is in testing and beta mode. For the easiest route, use the docker images for now in CPU-only mode.

Ref: [Docs](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=windows&configuration=compile)